# How to call onChange event JS function in Java/Selenium/WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, onchange

The below is JS function that triggers onChange on an element. This is working in JS...but how can I convert to Java / Selenium WebDriver.

Basically, I want to call as below...

```
    username.sendKeys("myName");
    triggerOnChange(username);
```

I tried using JavaScript Executor but does not work for me...

Any help would be appreciated...

---

```
triggerOnChange(selector) {
    if (browser.isIOS) {
        browser.execute((elementSelector) => {
            let input = document.querySelector(elementSelector);
            let lastValue = '';
            let event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
            let tracker = input._valueTracker;
            if (tracker) {
                tracker.setValue(lastValue);
            }
            input.dispatchEvent(event);
        }, selector);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am wondering how one can call the above JS function using Java/Selenium WebDriver...

Comment: Can you post the Java code you tried when attempting to execute the `triggerOnChange` function? Is the `triggerOnChange` function in the web page?